# ¿Cómo validar campos con if o switch mediante botón llamado "siguiente paso"?

Tags: javascript, html, validación

Estoy tratando de validar los campos de un formulario, trato de hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una estructura **`if`** y dentro de ella valida los campos si están vacíos o no, si uno de ellos están vacíos lanzaran una alerta de lo contrario no hará nada y seguirá al siguiente paso.

Para usar la validación JS tengo un botón llamado siguiente el cual me lleva a otro paso dentro del formulario sin recargar la página, es como un *wizard* de `boostrap` que es paso a paso, se me ocurre que si apretó el botón en la función if comienza el recorrido y empieza a validar campos, aquí el código:

```
function validar() {

    valor = document.getElementById("next_1").value;

    if (valor != ""){
        if ($('#vUserName').val().length == 0){ 
            alertify.alert('Debe Completar el Nombre de Usuario');
            $('#Preloader').modal('show');
            setTimeout("location.reload()", 15000);
        }
        if ($('#vEmailUsuario').val().length == 0){
            alertify.alert('Debe Completar el Correo electrónico');
            $('#Preloader').modal('show');
            setTimeout("location.reload()", 15000);
        }
        if ($('#vPassUsuario').val().length == 0){
            alertify.alert('Debe Completar Contraseña');
            $('#Preloader').modal('show');
            setTimeout("location.reload()", 15000);
        }
        if ($('#vPassUsuario_2').val().length == 0){ 
            alertify.alert('Debe Completar Verificar Contraseña');
            $('#Preloader').modal('show');
            setTimeout("location.reload()", 15000);
        }
        var duration = 15;
        var msg = alertify.message('Error Registro Reiniciando Formulario en '+ 
         (--duration)+' seg.', 15, function(){ clearInterval(interval);});

        var interval = setInterval(function(){
        msg.setContent('Error Registro Reiniciando Formulario en '+(--duration)+' seg.');
        },1000);        
   }
}
```

Hasta ahora se entiende que valida si está vacio se bloquea la pantalla en gris y se recarga la pagina con `reload` para borrar todo e iniciar de 0, pero no sé que hacer con el `if` principal que encierra a los demás se me ocurrio tratar de capturar el valor del boton al darle click entonces el `if` entendería que si se da click, comienza el recorrido

Tal vez no es la manera correcta de usar el `if` quizá debería usar `switch` pero aun así no sabría como definirlo, necesito ayuda.

Comment: Solo tienes que llamar a la funcion validar en el `onClick` del boton.  Otra cosa, reiniciar la pagina despues de validar no es amigable para el usuario.

Comment: Respondí una pregunta parecida al sitio de stackoverflow en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/a/50957353/5695795 dime si te sirve para agregarla